# Get Azure Devops Builds via Iterations and Rest API?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I know I can get builds for a project (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1), and I can get work items for an iteration (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/work/iterations/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP) by iteration Id (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/work/iterations/get-iteration-work-items?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP), but is there any way to traverse the Azure DevOps REST API's to get all the builds tied to an iteration Id?